# Mock file to upload with interface File[]

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am writing a test in Jasmine and I would like to test a function that has parameter files with type File[].

The function looks the following:

```
    onAddedFile(files: File[]) {
        if (files[0].type === 'text.plain') {
            this.fileToSend = files[0];
            this.uploadedFiles = [
                {
                    name: files[0].name,
                    progress: 0,
                }
            ];
        }
    }
```

I would like to test this function in Jasmine but I don't know how to mock a file type File[].

```
        it('should add file to upload module', () => {
            component.onAddedFile()
        })
```

Now the problem is that I need to pass file as a parameter but I'm getting different kind of errors saying the parameter is not type File[]. No matter how I modify the parameter, it's not good. Any idea how to mock a variable that is the right type and can be passed as file?

I've tried the following, but failed:

```
var file = new File([], "foo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the method is expecting an array of files and you're passing a file.

It wants `File[]` but you are giving `File`.

Try this (creating a file array):

```
it('should add file to upload module', () => {
  const file1 = new File([], "foo.txt", {
    type: "text/plain",
  });

  const file2 = new File([], "foo2.txt", {
    type: "text/plain",
  });

  const files = [file1, file2];
  component.onAddedFile(files);
 })
```